# Show product images on woocommerce new order email and completed order email

Tags: woocommerce

I'd like show images product in a new order and completed an order for customers.

I tried this code, but show big images in email, I need eg `100 x 100 px`

```
function sww_add_wc_order_email_images( $table, $order ) {

ob_start();

$template = $plain_text ? 'emails/plain/email-order-items.php' : 'emails/email-order-items.php';
wc_get_template( $template, array(
    'order'                 => $order,
    'items'                 => $order->get_items(),
    'show_download_links'   => $show_download_links,
    'show_sku'              => $show_sku,
    'show_purchase_note'    => $show_purchase_note,
    'show_image'            => true,
    'image_size'        => array( 100, 50 ),
    'image_size'            => $image_size
) );

return ob_get_clean();
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_table', 'sww_add_wc_order_email_images', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you already fixed this issue. I'm new here at StackOverflow and saw this question when looking for some other stuff :)

But I've just added this simple snippet to my `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Display Product Image in WooCommerce Order Emails
 * 
 * @author James Kemp (Iconic)
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_args', 'iconic_email_order_items_args', 10, 1 );

function iconic_email_order_items_args( $args ) {

    $args['show_image'] = true;

    return $args;

}
```

Comment: @biruk1230 How do you restrict this to new order email ONLY?